# How to select multiple points or markers programmatically in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How can I select multiple point or marker programmatically like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click on chart in default case of Highcharts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can select several points programatically using the `Point.select` function with `accumulate` set to `true`. The function signature is ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.select)):

> ```
> select ([Boolean select], [Boolean accumulate])
> ```

> `select`: Boolean.
> When `true`, the point is selected. When `false`, the point is unselected. When `null` or `undefined`, the selection state is toggled.

> `accumulate`: Boolean.
> When `true`, the selection is added to other selected points. When `false`, other selected points are deselected. Internally in Highcharts,selected points are accumulated on Control, Shift or Cmd clicking the point.

A example of your code would be:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].select(true, true);
chart.series[0].data[1].select(true, true);
// ...
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/3tnmesjc/) of how it can select several points.